# MySql. How can i get count from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, TableA and TableB

### TableA

```
IdA | Date       | Description  
--- | ---------- | -----------
1   | 2017-01-01 | Sometext1
2   | 2017-01-01 | Sometext2
3   | 2017-01-02 | Sometext3
4   | 2017-01-03 | Sometext4
```

---

### TableB

```
IdB | IdA | Type
--- | --- | ----
1   | 1   | A  
2   | 1   | A
3   | 2   | A
4   | 2   | A
5   | 2   | B 
6   | 3   | B
7   | 4   | A
```

---

### How can I get value like this :

```
Count(IdA) | Type        
---------- | ---- 
3          | A
```

I have tried to code using INNER or LEFT JOIN like

```
SELECT COUNT(tablea.IdA), tableb.Type
FROM tablea INNER JOIN tableb
ON tablea.IdA=tableb.IdA
WHERE tableb.Type='A'
```

But it always get me like this

```
Count(IdA) | Type
---------- | ----
5          | A
```

I just want to count TableA row with WHERE clause from TableB.
Is it possible to do something like that?

Comment: Are you looking for `COUNT(DISTINCT IdA)`?

Comment: @shmosel Post it as an answer :-)

Comment: @shmosel. Yes, I just tried COUNT(DISTINCT) and it works. Thanks for your reply. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want `COUNT(DISTINCT col)`.

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT a.IdA), b.Type
FROM
    tablea a
        INNER JOIN
    tableb b ON a.IdA = b.IdA
WHERE
    b.Type = 'A'
GROUP BY b.type
```

Comment: Thanks @GurV for your answer. :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need distinct column ids (but here's an answer using alias)

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct A.IdA), B.Type
FROM tablea A
INNER JOIN tableb B ON (A.IdA = B.IdA)
WHERE B.Type = 'A'
```

And you don't even need to put an ON clause if you join by the same column name so, making the sql even shorter.

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct A.IdA), B.Type
FROM tablea A
INNER JOIN tableb B
WHERE B.Type = 'A'
```